# How to next Youtube Video using Android Player API?

Tags: android, youtube-data-api

I developed an app using YouTube DATA API. I play single video but i want to use the next button to next the video. I use YouTube player to play video & i pass the video id to the video player.

Now How can i next the video?

here is my code what i am using to play single video

```
public  class PlayerViewDemoActivity extends YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity {

private String vedio_id;

protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
    return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
}

public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    requestWindowFeature(1);
    setContentView(R.layout.playerview_demo);
    this.vedio_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("videoId");
    ((YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view)).initialize("AIzaSyCojCp66RLS9OY8hOwnW0UWLNdC56z24Os", this);
}

public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider paramProvider, YouTubePlayer paramYouTubePlayer, boolean paramBoolean) {
    if (!paramBoolean) {
        paramYouTubePlayer.loadVideo(this.vedio_id);
        paramYouTubePlayer.play();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: edited my question :)

Answer (score 0):

if you only pass the video id to the video player you have to pass the new video id to play new.

```
paramYouTubePlayer.loadVideo(idVideo);
```

In your example you have to create a **new attribute** `private YoutubePlayer paramYoutubePlayer;`.

Next, you can create a new method like this:

```
public void nextVideo (String idVideo)
{
        paramYouTubePlayer.loadVideo(idVideo);
        paramYouTubePlayer.play();
}
```

But you can load an array of videos with:

```
loadVideos(List<String> videoIds)
```

and once you have loaded the List, you can call the `next()` and `previous()` methods on the `youtubePlayer` object.

Hope it helps!

Comment: i am having a problem to loadVideos. That's why i need a complete code

Comment: Your code looks nice, debug if you are receiving the video_id correctly and if the API Key is correct.

Comment: My code is only playing single video but i want to play next video. & that's my main problem

Comment: I think i m not understanding you. So, you don't have problem loadVideos, you can load one video. For load nextVideo you need the new videoId and call the method i wrote for you.

Comment: I have two major problem

1. I don't load the many videos. I can only load **ONE** video.
2. I can't go to the next video.

can u please give the full code?Please